# Questions about how to input both odds and payoff into expected value function

Tags: probability

I have a couple questions about probability. I'm having trouble understanding how to 1) put both odds and payoffs (as percentage) into an expected value function; and, 2) how to predict the "chip count"/assets of the gambler after repeated plays. Here's the scenario:

Suppose a gambler has favorable odds. There is a chance he wins 5% or loses 5% of his chip stack with respective probabilities $0.64% and %0.36$.

1. I believe it is valid to express the single-iteration expected value function as: $$E[X] = 1(0.64) - 1(0.36) $$ Since they payoffs are equal we can treat them as binary outcomes. How do we modify this for when the amount won differs from the amount lost? I.e., if payoff was 2.5% but loss is 5%? Also, what is the general format for an expected value function when the return is not a constant, per se, but a percentage?
2. The answer to this question may be obvious once 1. is answered. But anyways, I'm not sure if this is still called an expected value function, but how do we express the expected value function for repeated iterations? I.e., if the gambler plays $10, 100, ..., n$ times, what do we expect his chip count to be?

For example, if a gambler has $50/50$ odds of winning and losing, and there is equal payoff/loss, then it is expected that the gambler will go broke, I believe, even though the $E[X] = 0$ in this case. At least, this is the case when the payoff/loss are percentages, but probably not the case when it is a constant, so long as the gambler has a certain amount greater than the loss amount in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit expectation formulas you are looking for are
$(q_{\mathrm{win}}p_{\mathrm{win}}+q_{\mathrm{loss}}p_{\mathrm{loss}})^n S_0={\mathrm{E}}[S_n]$ ,
where upon winning or losing the current amount is multiplied by $q_{\mathrm{win}}$ or $q_{\mathrm{loss}}$ respectively,
$n(g_{\mathrm{win}}p_{\mathrm{win}}-g_{\mathrm{loss}}p_{\mathrm{loss}})+S_0={\mathrm{E}}[S_n]$ ,
where the win and loss amounts are fixed, $g_{\mathrm{loss}}$ and $g_{\mathrm{loss}}$ respectively.

Below I will show three ways to derive the first formula and at the very bottom I have derived the second formula.  To begin, let us analyze how the random variables are related to the constants given by the game rules in the percentage-based payoff case:

$p_{\mathrm{win}}$ probability to win a play (fixed $0<p_{\mathrm{win}}< 1$), let $p_{\mathrm{loss}}=1-p_{\mathrm{win}}$;
$g_{\mathrm{win}}$ percentage won per win (fixed $g_{\mathrm{win}}\geq 0$), let $q_{\mathrm{win}}=1+g_{\mathrm{win}}$;
$g_{\mathrm{loss}}$ percentage lost per loss (fixed $g_{\mathrm{loss}}\geq 0 $), let $q_{\mathrm{loss}}=1-g_{\mathrm{loss}}$;
$S_0$ the amount the gambler begins the game with;
$S_n$ the amount he has after the $n$th play. $S_n$ is a different discrete random variable for each $n$.

Then $S_1$ is the amount the gambler has after the 1st play.
Given the rules, there are 2 possible values for $S_1$:
$S_1=S_0(1+g_{\mathrm{win}})=q_{\mathrm{win}}S_0$ ,
if the gambler wins the $1$st play. This has a probability $p_{\mathrm{win}}$ to occur.
$S_1=S_0(1-g_{\mathrm{loss}})=q_{\mathrm{loss}}S_0$ ,
if the gambler loses the $1$st play. This has a probability $p_{\mathrm{loss}}$ to occur.

Now the expected value of any discrete random variable such as $S_1$, is by definition the sum of the products of each possible value with its probability of occurrence, that is
${\mathrm{E}}[S_1]=p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}S_0+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}}S_0=S_0(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})$
Note ${\mathrm{E}}[S_1]={\mathrm{E}}[S_1|S_0]={\mathrm{E}}[S_1|S_0=\bar{S_0}]$, the *conditional* expectation for $S_1$ on condition the gambler started with $S_0=\bar{S_0}$, where $\bar{S_0}$ is any fixed constant.

For $S_n$ we can repeat the same considerations:
$S_n=S_{n-1}(1+g_{\mathrm{win}})=q_{\mathrm{win}}S_{n-1}$ ,
if the gambler wins the $n$th play. This has a probability $p_{\mathrm{win}}$ to occur.
$S_n=S_{n-1}(1-g_{\mathrm{loss}})=q_{\mathrm{loss}}S_{n-1}$ ,
if the gambler loses the $n$th play. This has a probability $p_{\mathrm{loss}}$ to occur.
Note $S_n=S_n(S_{n-1})$ is a recursive formula and $S_n$ is a function of the previous random variable $S_{n-1}$.

Because $S_n$ depends on $S_{n-1}$, knowing the value of $S_{n-1}$ we can find the *conditional* expectation of $S_n$ on condition $S_{n-1}=\bar{S_{n-1}}$, where $\bar{S_{n-1}}$ is any fixed constant:
${\mathrm{E}}[S_n|S_{n-1}]=p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}S_{n-1}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}}S_{n-1}=S_{n-1}(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})=\\
={\mathrm{E}}[S_n|S_{n-1}=\bar{S_{n-1}}]=\bar{S_{n-1}}(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})$

Note ${\mathrm{E}}[S_n|S_{n-1}] \neq {\mathrm{E}}[S_n]\quad \forall n \neq 1$:
${\mathrm{E}}[S_n|S_{n-1}]$ is what the gambler is expected to have after $1$ play if he now has $S_{n-1}=\bar{S_{n-1}}$ after already having played $n-1$ times, so it is a function of the random variable $S_{n-1}$;
${\mathrm{E}}[S_n]$ is what he is expected to have after $n$ plays if he started with $S_0$, the total expectation for $S_n$, independent of all previous random values $\{S_j\}_{j=1}^{n-1}$.

By the law of total expectation we can express
${\mathrm{E}}[S_n]={\mathrm{E}}[{\mathrm{E}}[S_n|S_{n-1}]]=\\  
={\mathrm{E}}[S_{n-1}(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})]=\\
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}}){\mathrm{E}}[S_{n-1}]=\\
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}}){\mathrm{E}}[{\mathrm{E}}[S_{n-1}|S_{n-2}]]=\\
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}}){\mathrm{E}}[S_{n-2}(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})]=\\  
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})^2{\mathrm{E}}[S_{n-2}]=$
.../iteratively using the law of total expectation/...
$=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})^{n-1}{\mathrm{E}}[S_1]=\\
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})^{n-1}{\mathrm{E}}[{\mathrm{E}}[S_1|S_0]]=\\
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})^{n-1}{\mathrm{E}}[S_0(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})]=\\
=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})^n{\mathrm{E}}[S_0]=$
.../$S_0$ is constant so ${\mathrm{E}}[S_0]=S_0$, and also ${\mathrm{E}}[S_1]={\mathrm{E}}[S_1|S_0]$/...
$=(p_{\mathrm{win}}q_{\mathrm{win}}+p_{\mathrm{loss}}q_{\mathrm{loss}})^n S_0={\mathrm{E}}[S_n]$ ,
which is good explicit form of the expected value function, dependent only on $n$.

Also, there is an explicit expression for $S_n$:
$S_n(W)=q_{\mathrm{win}}^W q_{\mathrm{loss}}^L S_0=q_{\mathrm{win}}^W q_{\mathrm{loss}}^{n-W} S_0={\mathrm{E}}[Sn|W]$,
$W$ number of wins from $1$st to $n$th play (included);
$n-W=L$ number of losses from $1$st to $n$th play (included).
$W$ is another discrete random variable, the number of successes with probability $p_{\mathrm{win}}$ out of $n$ independent identical experiments (binomial distribution), i.e. $W \in {\mathrm{Bi}}(n,p_\mathrm{win})$, so
$\mathrm{P}(W=k)={n \choose k} p_{\mathrm{win}}^k (1-p_\mathrm{win})^{n-k}$ and $\mathrm{E}[W]=np_\mathrm{win}$.

Thus we can express the explicit probability for $S_n$ to be any particular number $s(k)$, where
$s(k)=q_{\mathrm{win}}^k q_{\mathrm{loss}}^{n-k} S_0$, depending on the event $W=k$, where $k$ is any fixed constant:
$\mathrm{P}(S_n=s(k))=\mathrm{P}(W=k)={n \choose k} p_{\mathrm{win}}^k (1-p_\mathrm{win})^{n-k}=\mathrm{P}(S_n=q_{\mathrm{win}}^k q_{\mathrm{loss}}^{n-k}S_0)$

Then we can also find $\mathrm{E}[S_n]$ by summing the products of the possible values of $S_n$  with their respective probabilities
$\mathrm{E}[S_n]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}s(k){n \choose k} p_{\mathrm{win}}^k (1-p_\mathrm{win})^{n-k}=\\  
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (q_{\mathrm{win}}^k q_{\mathrm{loss}}^{n-k}S_0) {n \choose k} p_{\mathrm{win}}^k (1-p_\mathrm{win})^{n-k}$
or again by the law of the total expectation
$\mathrm{E}[S_n]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[S_n|W]]=\mathrm{E}[q_{\mathrm{win}}^W q_{\mathrm{loss}}^{n-W} S_0]=S_0\mathrm{E}[q_{\mathrm{win}}^W q_{\mathrm{loss}}^{n-W}]$ ,
however the above computations are not as simple as the first form of $\mathrm{E}[S_n]$ we found.

Now for the case where the win and loss amounts are fixed and not percentages, it is even simpler to define $S_n$:
$g_{\mathrm{win}}$ amount won per win;
$g_{\mathrm{loss}}$ amount lost per loss;
$S_n=S_0+Wg_{\mathrm{win}}-Lg_{\mathrm{loss}}=S_0+Wg_{\mathrm{win}}-  (n-W)g_{\mathrm{loss}}=$
$=S_0+W(g_{\mathrm{win}}+g_{\mathrm{loss}})-ng_{\mathrm{loss}}$ .
Then for the expected value we have
$\mathrm{E}[S_n]=\mathrm{E}[S_0+W(g_{\mathrm{win}}+g_{\mathrm{loss}})-ng_{\mathrm{loss}}]=$
$=S_0-ng_{\mathrm{loss}}+  (g_{\mathrm{win}}+g_{\mathrm{loss}})\mathrm{E}[W]=$
$=S_0-ng_{\mathrm{loss}}+(g_{\mathrm{win}}+g_{\mathrm{loss}})np_{\mathrm{win}}=S_0+n((g_{\mathrm{win}}+g_{\mathrm{loss}})p_{\mathrm{win}}-g_{\mathrm{loss}}))=$
$=S_0+n(g_{\mathrm{win}}p_{\mathrm{win}}-g_{\mathrm{loss}}(1-p_{\mathrm{win}}))=S_0+n(g_{\mathrm{win}}p_{\mathrm{win}}-g_{\mathrm{loss}}p_{\mathrm{loss}})$ .

Finally, by using the explicit formulas for the expectations, you can figure out the exact amount the gambler is expected to have after playing $n$ times.
Counterintuitively (but evident from the formulas), you will find that
$\mathrm{E}[S_n]=S_0\quad\forall g_{\mathrm{win}}$=$g_{\mathrm{loss}},\, p_{\mathrm{win}}$=$p_{\mathrm{loss}}$=$\frac{1}{2}$ ,
which does mean that the gambler is not expected to either lose or get rich by playing infinitely.